# Does Google Developer Console provide an API?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I am looking for API access to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com). Is there a public API to enable/disable/view usage of certain services inside of the developer console?

Answer (score 1):

not yet, no. You have the [AppIdentity API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/) that can provide some "admin" stuff, but VERY little, and nothing really related to any services or quotas or anything. All it does is give you your appID, your default version hostname, and small stuff like that.